# Returning the DISTINCT first character of a field (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to produce a character list of all of the first letters of column in my database. The SQL below illistrats what I would like to return.

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_character(name) FROM mydatabase
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

**EDIT**
What is the advantage of using SUBSTRING over LEFT and vice versa?

**EDIT**
Currently there are about 1700 records in the table and growing.

Comment: How many records do you have in your table? I wanted to post an optimized version but don't know whether to bother :)

Comment: OK, I posted it anyway :) Probably tomorrow I'll make a post in my blog out of your question.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Sorry to do this, but I figured out exactly what I needed to do just now.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(name, 1) FROM table;
```

This returned a list of the first, distinct, single characters that each row in the column started with. I changed it to the following to get the list in alphanumeric order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(name, 1) AS letter FROM table ORDER BY letter;
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to post answers to your own questions. +1

Comment: I use `SUBSTRING()` because it's a SQL standard.  I haven't found a standard for the `LEFT()` function. http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#functions-SUBSTRING

Answer (score 10):

Sounds simple:

```
select distinct substring(field,1,1) as char
from mytable
```

Comment: SQL standard usage: `SUBSTRING(input FROM start-position [FOR length])` -> `SUBSTRING(field FROM 1 FOR 1)`

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "Incorrect syntax" the syntax I posted is shown here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring - The full query would be this: `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(field FROM 1 FOR 1) AS char FROM mytable`

Comment: @Sonny: Apologies, I assumed this question was about SQL Server, but it's about MySQL.

Comment: That's good to know! I would have assumed that using the SQL standard would make the query more portable, rather than less.  MySQL also supports the `SUBSTRING(field, 1, 1)` syntax.

Answer (score 10):

For your current table of `1,700` rows your solution is OK.

If you will have like `100,000` of rows, the `DISTINCT` may become inefficient.

Here's the article in my blog that shows how to do it efficiently:

- [**Selecting first letters**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/08/selecting-first-letters/)

This solution employs an index on `name`. It will jump over the index keys, selecting each first letter at most once.

First, you'll need to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_next_code(initial INT) RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
        DECLARE _next VARCHAR(200);
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN NULL;
        SELECT  ORD(SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1))
        INTO    _next
        FROM    t_names
        WHERE   name >= CHAR(initial + 1)
        ORDER BY
                name
        LIMIT 1;
        RETURN _next;
END
```

This function, given a code of a starting letter, returns the first starting letter next to the given from your table.

Second, use this function in a query:

```
SELECT  CHAR(@r) AS starting,
        @r := fn_get_next_letter(@r) AS next
FROM    (
        SELECT @r := ORD(LEFT(MIN(name), 1))
        ) vars, mytable
WHERE   @r IS NOT NULL
```

On each iteration, session variable `@r` will skip to the next starting letter using an index.

This will be very fast, but it pays for itself only if you have hundreds of thousands of rows.

Otherwise just use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: +1, bookmarked for when I have to query the United Nations table of all named entities in the universe :D