# Product Index Using Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have a list of Products with a field called 'Title' and I have been trying to get a list of initial letters with not much luck. The closes I have is the following that dosn't work as 'Distinct' fails to work.

```
atoz = Product.objects.all().only('title').extra(select={'letter': "UPPER(SUBSTR(title,1,1))"}).distinct('letter')
```

I must be going wrong somewhere,
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in python after the queryset got in, which is trivial:

```
products = Project.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).distinct()
atoz = set([i[0] for i in products])
```

If you are using mysql, I found [another answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837058/returning-the-distinct-first-character-of-a-field-mysql), albeit using sql([django execute sql directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(title, 1) FROM product;
```

Comment: Yes the SQL is exactly what I want BUT in the Django ORM if possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything existed in ORM that implements `LEFT` substring function in mysql. Maybe there's another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could come up with, which isn't 100% ideal as it requires post processing is this.

```
atoz = sorted(set(Product.objects.all().extra(select={'letter': "UPPER(SUBSTR(title,1,1))"}).values_list('letter', flat=True)))
```