# Mysql - How to search for 26 records that each begins with the letter of the alphabet?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I'm trying to create a query that can retrieve 26 words from a table based on the letters of the English alphabet (26 letters).  So "Apple, Banana, Coconut..." etc.

I've been using 'like a%', so:

`SELECT * from 'word' WHERE word_name like 'a%' limit 1` - which gives me a word that begins with 'a'.

`SELECT * from 'word' WHERE word_name like 'a%' or word_name like 'b%'` - which gives me multiple words beginning with 'a' or 'b'.

`SELECT * FROM`word`WHERE word_name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'e'` - list all words that begins with a-e.  Seems more powerful.  From here, I need to know how to limit the query to finding just one word per letter and 26 words in total, I've tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word_name FROM `word` WHERE word_name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' limit 26;

SELECT DISTINCT word_name FROM `word` WHERE word_name like [a-z]% limit 26;
```

I feel like I'm getting the right idea but neither of these are working for me.  I'm familiar with php so I could go the really long route and create a query for every letter and put that into an array, but is there already a mysql solution for this?

Comment: 26 selects with union? (no there has to be a better way :0)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I tried your query but it still gives me all the words beginning with a,b,c etc (so instead of a max 26 words I'm getting 1987 words). I'm trying to get one word per letter.  And yes there has to be a better way.

Comment: thats why i deleted, its distinct on 2 not one col... testing a few ideas locally at the mo

Comment: I found a related solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837058/returning-the-distinct-first-character-of-a-field-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(word_name, 1) as letter, word_name
FROM word
 GROUP BY (letter)
 ORDER BY letter
```

Comment: That indeed!  So basically using distinct left was the right idea, and getting the first letter and using an alias which is then used to be grouped and ordered by.

Comment: Is there a way to get 2 words of each letter?

Comment: Ok by modifying the first query using "SELECT LEFT(word_name, 2)" this will return words with the first 2 characters that are unique.

Answer (score 2):

How about `group by` the first letter of each word?

```
SELECT word_name FROM `word` GROUP BY SUBSTRING(word_name,0,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't think of using "group by".