# Display in PHP first letter of mySql array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display businesses from within our database as an alphabetical list, sorted by first letter. Currently, Not all letters are represented. As a visual example, the user page would look like this:

Display business by name - 
| [A](https://#) | [C](https://#) | [F](https://#) | [G](https://#) | [H](https://#) | [L](https://#) | ...
(wheras each letter above would display the businesses that start with that letter.)

However, I'm having difficulty with displaying the mysql query result of the 'first letters' on the php page.
To generate the result as a query, I have the following line:

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT LEFT('bname', 1) FROM 'bisEntry');
```

(This came from [Returning the DISTINCT first character of a field (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837058/returning-the-distinct-first-character-of-a-field-mysql))

Then, to display the "first letter" of each business on the page, I have tried the following:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "| ". $row['bname'] ." ";
        }
```

With this first example, the array is correctly 'counting' for the different first letters and displaying this:

Display business by name - 
|  |  |  |  |  |  | ...

However, the actual letters aren't showing. I'm hung up on how to convert the results from the array, to the actual letters that will be displayed.

AND I tried...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4))
        {
            foreach ($row['category'] as $name) {
            echo "| ". $name;
            }
```

However, this returned the error
 `foreach() argument must be of type array|object` which leads me to beleive I am not actally creating the array correctly.

I'm sure the solution is in fromt of my nose, but I am just not able to untangle it. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Check the contents of `$row` as the column name is not what you think it is. You should be getting an error/warning for that statement.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you do not have column `bname` selected directly, so column name becomes `LEFT('bname', 1)` (e.g. `[["LEFT('bname', 1)" => 'A'], ["LEFT('bname', 1)" => 'C']]`). Add alias as column name:

```php
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT('bname', 1) AS bname FROM bisEntry");
```

---

You can always debug what is returned in your variables using xDebug or simply `var_dump($row);`